# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message) found in android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

[image]

It always shows when I injecting with a dagger. What happens or can I get a solution? please help me I am stuck 2 weeks in this code.

Comment: something goes wrong with your injection. 
it can be your component, module, or ...

Comment: Make sure you have all your dependencies up to date. And may be implementation of dagger is wrong. update question with dagger code snips.

Comment: Yes, I have been fixed with changing dependencies.Thanks for answering